start() is Deprecated in GRPC services
I'm using node version upper 20 and I faced deprecation warning in the GRPC file in this line of code exactly below the problem inlines with server.start():
 function main() {
  var server = new grpc.Server();
  server.addService(hello_proto.Greeter.service, {sayHello: sayHello});
  server.bindAsync('0.0.0.0:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), (error, port) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Server binding failed: ${error.message}`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(`Server running at http://0.0.0.0:${port}`);
    // server.start()
  });
}

I need to know what's the alternative way to start the server.

Please include the specific error that you're receiving. Is it "DeprecationWarning: Calling start() is no longer necessary. It can be safely omitted."? If so, the warning is unambiguous and it appears you've already made this change to your code.

The only change you need to make to address that warning is to remove the call to server.start().
